# Menu content does not collapse on click - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to bootstrap. I am currently working on Navbar. want to make it responsive on collapse. it works perfectly fine when i am working locally. But i see that menu bar does not close contents on click. I tried to use the CSS link and script link from CDN. also made use of the folders. But i suspect somewhere script is not loading as expected.

here is my code

```html
 <html>
    <!-- New: report inputs using textarea instead of single text line
    -->
    <head>
    
     <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
     <title> NB Sep 2016</title>
     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menubarStyle.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/NB_GUI2.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/awsModal.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PAmodal.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eventTable.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reportModal.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/textModal2.css">
     
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
      <!--<nav class="navbar navbar-default   ">  -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuItems" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>-->
        </div>
    
    
          <div class="navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
              <!--<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" ></span></a></li>-->
              <li> <a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" style="color:white">XYZ</a></li>  
             </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a style="color:white"><span>Welcome,Dr.David Yang </span></a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:brown"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
          </nav>
    
         
        
     <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fili.min.js"></script>
     <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>-->
    
     <script src="js/MyJS34-webviewer1-test7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/teechart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/teechart-extras.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/downloadify.min.js"></script>
    
    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic.js"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aws-sdk.js"></script>
    
        <!-- <script src="js/PreAnnotationModal6.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
     <script src="js/PreAnnotationModal7-webviewer1-test4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/AWSmodal3-webviewer1-test1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
     
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you check the console of Chrome for example if there is an error or something? Usually, when a CSS or JS file isn't loaded, Chrome gives an error/warning about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified your code it's working fine now

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
          </div>          
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left-sm">
             <li> <a href="#"></a></li>
             <li><a href="#" style="color:000">XYZ</a></li>  
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">            
             <li><a style="color:#000"><span>Welcome,Dr.David Yang </span></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:brown"></span></a></li>      
            </ul>
            <hr class="visible-xs visible-sm row"/>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in this line `<div class="navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">` add `collapse` class because the `data-toggle = "collapse"` is written on the button which is supposed to close.